# Convert a pipelined aggregation with scripting to kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Can [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) in elasticsearch be converted to a graph on kibana 4?

For e.g in the docs "t-shirt-percentage" example
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html

**Updates** :
Found that this is not yet supported -
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-4-2-beta-release-and-elastic-2-0-beta-pipeline-aggregations/28383

What's the alternative to achieve the same (pipeline aggregations) using Kibana 4 and ES 1.7.4 ?

Comment: The alternative is to run the aggregations you need and do the computations on the client side for each bucket and then push the resulting buckets as new documents into another index that you can then chart in Kibana.

Comment: did you find any solution?